# Dynamically generated .jsp files : PWC6117 error using jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I develop locally using Spring MVC, Maven and the jetty-maven-plugin plugin (7.6.2.v20120308).

I know some of you will think this is not a good idea, but I automatically generate some .jsp files. I have, for example, a **dyn.js** file which I want to be dynamic, to contain JSTL/EL code.

In short here's what I do :

- If the dynamic dyn.js is called and an interpreted cache version doesn't exist yet, I redirect the request to a special controller.
- The controller takes the content of the dyn.js file and create a **dyn.js.jsp** file with this content, in the same directory where my other .jsp files are. I get that directory, at runtime, using something like :

  ```
  getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "tags"
  ```
- Once the jsp file is generated, my controller returns the view path (or a ModelAndView) so the view can be processed.
- Once the view is finally rendered, I get the resulting content (using a custom Response wrapper in a filter), and I save it to a cache file.

This method works great! I'm pretty happy with it.

The only problem, is that sometimes I get this error when trying to generate the dynamic dyn.js :

```
Jul 8, 2012 5:15:12 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet _serviceJspFile
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\somepath\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\dyn.js.jsp" not found
```

When this happens, there is nothing to do. Even if I refresh the page the jsp is never found so my dyn.js doesn't work. I then check and the .jsp file **does exist** in my file system (C:\somepath\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\dyn.js.jsp)!

This issue seems to happen randomly. I'm not able to reproduce the problem at will. I'd say it happens 1/5 of the time.

It seems Jetty is not able to "see" the generated .jsp file in some situations.

Any idea what can triggers this issue and how I could fix it?

UPDATE : I use jetty-maven-plugin version 7.6.2.v20120308 .

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I think I found a workaround. Creating the temporary .jsp files, even without content in them, *before the first request* seems to fix the problem.

So when the application starts, I have a hook that creates the dynamic .jsp files with an empty content.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is about file path.When you copy the path on console and paste it on windows explorer you can not open the path.